# iOS8 Keyboard Extension get current context

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

how can I get the current text input state to toggle between email field, browser url field or text field. I want to display @ signs, open button or enter button depending on the current state. I searches and tried for days but could not find anything.

-- best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have direct access to the user's text field.

However, you have access via the text document proxy, which conforms to `UITextInputTraits`.

In your `KeyboardViewController`, you want to use `self.textDocumentProxy`'s following properties: `returnKeyType` and `keyboardType`